# Add non-generic methods to generic classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, repository

I'm using a unit of work / generic repository pattern almost identical to [the example Microsoft provides](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), and it works great. However, the need has recently arisen for some methods that are only applicable to a particular type of repository.

For example, say I have two classes corresponding to database tables: `People` and `Spaceships`.

`unitofwork.People` is a `Repository<Person>` and `unitofwork.Spaceships` is a `Repository<Spaceship>`. While both repositories have the methods I defined in

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
```

what if I want some `Person`-specific methods to be available on `unitofwork.People`? Is this possible?

Comment: That is where the idea with generic one-size-fits-all classes fail. Separate your concerns and create query classes for people separately from your repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `Repository<T>` an abstract class. Then each entity *must* have their own implementations:

```
abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity {
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    ...
}

class PeopleRepository : RepositoryBase<Person> {
    string GetPersonName();
}

class SpaceshipRepository : RepositoryBase<Spaceship> {
    void Fly();
}
```

You'd then implement the classes as:

```
unitofwork.People = new PeopleRepository();
unitofwork.People.Add(new Person()); // Can access the base class
Console.WriteLine(unitofwork.People.GetPersonName()); // People-specific methods
unitofwork.Spaceships = new SpaceshipRepository();
```

If you want to be able to initialise an instance of the base repository, there is no need to mark it as `abstract`:

```
class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity {
    void Add(TEntity entity);
}

class PeopleRepository : Repository<Person> {
    string GetPersonName();
}
```

If you want to stop the `PeopleRepository` from providing its own methods, then you can use the `sealed` modifier:

```
class Repository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity {
    sealed protected void Add(TEntity entity);
}
```

Comment: Yes! I knew there was something like this. Just couldn't remember what it was called. Abstract. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I don't want abstract, because I failed to mention there are yet other types I don't need specific methods on, and want to instantiate the generic repository. All I needed was inheriting the class, which seems painstakingly obvious in hindsight. I was overthinking it hard.

Comment: I think that means that the word "optionally" in your answer is technically incorrect. It looks like each entity *must* have its own implementation if the base class is `abstract`.

Comment: You're right, optionally was not the correct term to use as you cannot initiate an instance of an abstract class. I have updated the example to better explain